# Const empty object causes infinite re-render

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

Consider this dummified example:

```
export function myHook<TVariables = Record<string,string>> (variables?: TVariables) {

    const [result, setResult] = useState<number>();

    const fooFunction(variables?: TVariables) {
       //In real life : do something with the variables...
       setResult(666);
    }

    useEffect(() => 
      {
         fooFunction(variables);
      }, [variables])
    
    return result;
}
```

Later, in one of my components I use the hook like this :

```
export interface IMyVariables {
    //Empty. Just because.
}

const MyComponent: React.FunctionComponent = () => {

  const variables = {};

  const [result] = myHook<IMyVariables>(variables );

  return (
     <></>
  );
}
```

**PROBLEM :**

*const variables = {};* is not enough to guarantee that React sees that the variables *didn't* change. It actually thinks that they HAVE changed every time, causing an infinite re-render.

**BRUTE FORCE SOLUTION:**

This *useMemo* fixes the problem. As in : React understands that the value didn't change. So the component is rendered only once. And in other places where some other type IMyVariables2 *does* have fields, then it gets re-rendered if one of them changes.

`const params = useMemo(() => { return {}; }, []);`

**QUESTION:**
Is there a smarter way of achieving this? I.e. a smarter way of making React understand that {} === {} ?

**EDIT**

I thought that the issue was exactly the same when doing *const variables = **undefined*** as with *const variables = **{}*** .
**But it seems that *undefined* prevents the infinite loop** (which makes sense : React correctly determines that undefined === undefined).

I'm not sure why I had convinced myself otherwise. I think it might have been because of a colleague of mine who uses weak typing -- he passed the parameters in the wrong order, passing an actual value where it should have been undefined, and I didn't spot the mistake, wondering about the infinite loop.

Comment: Do you think making a function `const` guarantees that its return value is always the same? I don't follow your assumption here. If you don't want something to re-render, you have to make sure your function doesn't return new instances. You'll never be able to tell React that `{} === {}` because that's a lie.

Comment: It is indeed an incorrect assumption, and I apologize for irritating you.

Comment: You didn't irritate or annoy me , sorry if it sounded that way. I was just surprised by the assumption. I have seen people assume that `const a = {}` would make sure that object is not modifiable but that is not true. `const` only means that a reference to a value (object, number, function) cannot be reassigned to `a` by doing `a = {a:1}`. Another way to say it, `const` only applies to the variable name, not to the value itself. Thinking it could possible affect the result of a function is a really big stretch.

Comment: I understand. I should have known (references 101). I got fooled by the fact that "{}" looks too much like a literal, and therefore looks like it has a unique reference across the app's lifecycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to reinitate the variables each render? You should keep them inside a state or something else:

```
const MyComponent: React.FunctionComponent = () => {

  const [variables, setVariables] = useState({});

  const [result] = myHook<IMyVariables>(variables);

  return (
    <></>
  );
}
```

you can also use a `useRef`, or put it outside of the component, but it depends on what the variable should be and when it will change.

As i think you will change the variables somehow the `setState` would be the best solution, and it will also update the hook after calling `setVariables(...)`.

If they never change anyway use:

```
const variables = {};

const MyComponent: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  const [result] = myHook<IMyVariables>(variables);

  return (
    <></>
  );
}
```

Comment: I don't *want* to do it, it's just what comes naturally to me as a dev : Something doesn't change => declare it as const and be done with it.  I'm guessing your suggestion is similar to the useMemo solution, but with useState instead. Noted.

Comment: if it doesn't change and will always be the same, put it outside of the component.

Comment: `const variables = {};

const MyComponent: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  const [result] = myHook<IMyVariables>(variables);

  return (
    <></>
  );
}`

Comment: My issue only arises in the situation where 'myHook' doesn't have variables. In all other cases, yes, I store them in the state. I'm looking for the solution when variables should be empty. OK, I also take in consideration your suggestion of storing the const outside the omponent.

Comment: another way would be to write a custom hook where you shallow compare the values: something like this: https://github.com/sandiiarov/use-deep-compare or just doing your ohne deepequal compare hook.

Comment: I edited the question : *undefined* works, and I had fooled myself into believing it doesn't.

Comment: @jeancallisti That's because `undefined === undefined`  same will happen if your functions returns [any other primitive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive).